# How to access center of polygons after remesh

Tags: python, mesh, topology, operator

I'm working on a method to compare distances in a space in Python. I am only using the GUI to check my results; all operations are done via a Python script.

I am using the remesh operator to increase the number of faces of a given primative, so that I can find a pseudo-accurate distance to the object by finding the closest face.

I was able to get the remesh to work. However, I'm having trouble accessing the new polygons. It seems there are only the original centers available.. although I am able to see when loading Blender that the number of faces have increased. So, the number of face-centers should also?!

Before:
[image: before remesh]

After:
[image: after remesh]

In the console:

```
>>> ob.data.polygons[:]
[bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[0], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[1], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[2], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[3], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[4], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[5], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[6], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[7], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[8], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[9], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[10], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[11], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[12], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[13], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[14], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[15], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[16], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[17], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[18], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[19], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[20], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[21], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[22], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[23], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[24], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[25], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[26], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[27], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[28], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[29], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[30], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[31], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[32], bpy.data.meshes['slab'].polygons[33]]
```

Clearly more than 33 polygons! Any ideas?

I've tried:

- after remeshing

  `bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
  bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()`
- after remeshing `ob.data.update(calc_edges=True)`
- when reading `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')`

Comment: For one thing, you're not going to see the faces of the centers in object mode.. You'll need to be in edit mode to view these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying the modifier, you can convert the object into a mesh:

[How can curves be converted to meshes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/how-can-curves-be-converted-to-meshes)

This will "flatten" the results you expected from the modifier into the mesh and you will see the transformed vertices and be able to select them in edit mode.

Comment: Good deal, I realized that I was applying the mesh in the wrong mode. Fixed with:
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT'); bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Remesh");